# Use implicit typeclass parameter for default argument

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

Consider the following code.

```
def create[A: Ordering]: Unit = ()

case class Test[A: Ordering](x: Unit = create[A])
```

The compiler complaints, because in the second line, he cannot find the implicit argument that is required for the call to `create`:

> ScalaFiddle.scala:5: error: No implicit Ordering defined for A.   case
>   class Test[A: Ordering](x: Unit = create[A])

Why is this happening, as there should be an `Ordering[A]` hanging around?
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by **compiler** will try to translate the:

```
case class Test[A: Ordering](x: Unit = create[A])
```

to:

```
case class Test[A](x: Unit = create[A])(implicit ordering: Ordering[A])
```

as you can see, the compiler can't find the `implicit Ordering` parameter for **default**  `create[A]`, below is a simple example for prove this:

```
scala> def foo[A: Ordering](): Unit = ()
foo: [A]()(implicit evidence$1: Ordering[A])Unit

scala> def bar[A: Ordering](x: Unit = foo[A]): Unit = ()
<console>:12: error: No implicit Ordering defined for A.
       def bar[A: Ordering](x: Unit = foo[A]): Unit = ()

scala> def bar[A: Ordering](x: Unit = foo[Double]): Unit = ()
bar: [A](x: Unit)(implicit evidence$1: Ordering[A])Unit
```

for the solution, maybe you can use a `class` to bind the `Ordering`, maybe like:

```
class Foo[A](implicit ordering: Ordering[A]) {
  def create: Unit = ()
  case class Test(x: Unit = create)
}
```